# How to add option tex of outreg2 in the last iteration of a loop

Tags: loops, stata

I am using the *community-contributed* command `outreg2` to produced a `LaTeX` table.

According to the help file:

> outreg2 cannot append TeX format tables to one another, so
>       regressions must be appended in ASCII form until the last regression,
>       which is appended with the tex option.

As such, when I run several regressions in a loop, I need to identify the last iteration somehow in order to add the `tex` option.

In my own attempt, by using `local append` I manage to specify option `replace` for the first loop and option `append` to subsequent loops:

```
global dvars var1 var2 var3

local append "replace"
foreach dvar in $dvars {
    reg `dvar' treatment
    outreg2 using "file", `append'
    local append "append"
}
```

Is there something similar to add the option `tex` to the last loop?

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `word count` macro extended function (see `help extended_fcn`) to identify the number of elements in the list you are looping over, and add a counter to your loop to count the number of loops. Using the `if` command (`help ifcmd`) you can identify the final loop and change the options for `outreg2` accordingly.

Note the change to the `foreach` loop syntax, since you are working directly with a `global`.

```
global dvars var1 var2 var3
local iterations : word count $dvars
local i = 0

foreach dvar of global dvars {
    // augment iteration counter
    local ++i

    // define options (over-specified, but you can revise as desired)
    if `i' == 1 local options "replace"
    else if `i' > 1 & `i' < `iterations' local options "append"
    else if `i' == `iterations' local options "append tex"

    // run regression & outreg2
        // for now, just display command
    *reg `dvar' treatment
    di as result `"outreg2 using "file", `options'"'
}

di as result "number of loops = `i'"
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to find the iteration number or create counter macros. In this case, the final iteration of the `foreach` loop happens when the *last* variable of `dvars` is called.

Here is a minimal reproducible example using Stata's `auto` toy dataset:

```
sysuse auto, clear

local dvars mpg weight length
local append "replace"

foreach dvar in `dvars' {
    display "regress `dvar' i.foreign"
    if `dvar' == length local tex tex
    display `"outreg2 using "file", `append' `tex'"'
    local append "append"
}

regress mpg i.foreign
outreg2 using "file", replace 
regress weight i.foreign
outreg2 using "file", append 
regress length i.foreign
outreg2 using "file", append tex
```

Note that it is best to use local macros as opposed to global 
ones whenever possible.